# Uploading Photos, Videos and Audio

Tags: facebook, video

Will the guys at FB approve apps that upload photos, videos and audio files?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's all there in the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/. If you read it, you will be able to see all the limitations.

For example, here are references for Photo and Video.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/